# Problemas com Xampp

Tags: php, aplicação-web, xampp

Acabei de fazer a instalação do xampp e ao digitar, no terminal:

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Aparece alguns problemas, segue a imagem do terminal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse comando abaixo não fui eu que digitei, aparece sozinho:

```
$ /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 264: kill: No surch process
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: consegue compartilhar seu error_log

Comment: te aconselho a reinstalar

Comment: Desinstalei e reinstalei, deu certo!